# How to add a filter to a Visual Studio Project via the IVsProject interface?

Tags: filter, project, visual-studio-addins

Using [IVsProject.AddItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsproject.additem%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), I can add an existing file to the root of my Visual Studio project.
I use the following piece of code :

```
string[] files = new string[1] { file };
VSADDRESULT[] result = new VSADDRESULT[1];
proj.AddItem(
    VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT,
    VSADDITEMOPERATION.VSADDITEMOP_OPENFILE,
    file,
    1,
    files,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    result);
```

However, I would like to add filters to my project, and move this file under one of those filters.
Can I use code similar to the sample aboveto do so ? How can I refer to a filter after creating it ?